# Removing coins from a pile depending on the previous move

Tags: mathematics, strategy, game

Alice and Bob play a game taking turns. There is one pile of $n\geq2$ identical coins on a table.
Alice starts and with her first move she takes away at least one coin from the pile, but not all of them. After that move the next player takes at least one coin but not more than the amount of coins, which was taken away on the preceding move. The person who takes the last coin, wins.
Who has a winning strategy?

Comment: I am curious if you invented this Puzzle (if so: RESPECT) or if you spotted it, or crafted it from existing one (and, still: RESPECT).

Comment: I didn't invent it, a friend asked me about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that

> Alice wins unless $n$ is a power of $2$.

Proof

> Clearly Alice wins all odd numbers, by removing one coin at the beginning, and it's trivial to show that Bob wins when $n$ is $2$ or $4$ so we just need to prove the statement for even numbers greater than $4$, which we'll do by induction.
>  We already have the base step. Suppose the premise is true for all even numbers less than $n$. We will prove it for $n$.
>  Suppose $n$ is a power of $2$, firstly.
>  If Alice removes at least half the coins then Bob can remove the rest to win the game. Suppose Alice removes some number of coins $k$ less than $n/2$. Then Bob finds the smallest power of $2$ strictly greater than $k$ ($2^m$, say) and removes $2^m-k$ coins. Note that $2^m - k \leq k$ which allows Bob to make this move. Bob can apply this general strategy after each of Alice's moves to win the game because it guarantees that it will be Alice's move whenever they land on a number of coins that is a power of 2.
>  To see why this is true, imagine we represent the total number of coins in binary and suppose that a move by Alice has $m$ digits in binary. Then Bob's next move guarantees that the binary representation of the remaining number of coins ends with $m$ zeroes while each of Alice's subsequent moves can have at most $m$ digits in its binary representation. This allows Bob to continue the strategy on each subsequent step and because each power of $2$ is represented as a $1$ followed by all $0$s, only Bob may arrive at these after the first move.
>  Now suppose $n$ is not a power of $2$.
>   Alice just finds the largest power of $2$ less than $n$  ($2^p$, say) and removes $n-2^p$ coins. This leaves a losing position for Bob, since $n-2^p < 2^p$ and Alice can just copy Bob's strategy from the previous paragraph.

Comment: If n is 6 and Alice takes 2, how will Bob win? If he takes 2 Alice wins by taking remaining 2 and if he takes 1 Alice wins (as n is now 3 and odd).

Comment: @FirstNameLastName n=6 is winning for Alice since 6 is not a power of 2.

Comment: I apologize, I had (mis)read n even...

Comment: I don't think this proof is valid because the state is dependent on more than just the number of coins in the pile. "This leaves a losing position for Bob" and "... is a losing position for Alice by the assumption" are actually skipping over some important steps.

Comment: The losing position for Bob is actually easy to explain - leaving Bob with 2^m coins isn't the same as starting with 2^m coins, but because it only leaves Bob with fewer options it's still a losing position. However for Alice it's not so easy - for example if n=16, Alice can take two and leave Bob with n=14 *but only able to take max 2*. So you need to show that leaving Bob with fewer options can't prevent it from being a winning position.

Comment: @RobWatts Thank you for your comments, I've modified the solution now which I think should work.

Comment: I think the proof is still incomplete. For example, suppose $n=16$ and Alice takes 2. Then Bob takes 2. This results in $n=12$ which Alice would win if she could choose 4 (but she can't). The proof seems to say nothing about this case except the vague "it will be Alice's move whenever they land on a number of coins that is a power of 2" (which I think is true, but not sufficiently justified).

Comment: I guess my argument would be maybe along the lines: rot13(Nsgre Nyvpr unf pubfra x naq Obo unf pubfra 2^z-x, vs Obo pbagvahrf gur tvira fgengrtl, gur tnzr jvyy orunir yvxr n frevrf bs tnzrf bs fvmr 2^z (cbffvoyl jvgu zber erfgevpgvbaf ba Nyvpr), naq gur erznvavat ahzore bs pbvaf vf vaqrrq qvivfvoyr ol 2^z naq Obo jvyy vaqrrq jva rnpu fznyyre tnzr.).

Comment: @tehtmi Apologies, I think this was something that was obvious to me but maybe not to others. I will try to add a line to clarify.

Comment: @tehtmi I've now added a paragraph in order to clarify why the strategy works for Bob.

Comment: Can you please explain what this means , "This allows Bob to continue the strategy on each subsequent step and because each power of 2 is represented as a 1 followed by all 0s, only Bob may arrive at these after the first move." Also what is "these" here ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal The strategy for Bob is that whenever Alice picks up $k$ coins, Bob finds the smallest power of 2 greater than k ($2^m$ say) and picks up $2^m - k$ coins. The previous explanation guarantees that Bob is always able to do this. "these" here refers to powers of 2.

Comment: I am not able to understand why it is guaranteed that  Bob will always win . The explanation is not very clear still. Also, not able to understand why this strategy works only when the number of coins is a power of 2 . Because, if the starting number of coins is 64 and Alice picks 5 coins then Bob will pick 3 coins. This will leave a total of 56 coins. Shouldn't Alice win now because 56 is not a power of 2 ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal No, because as Rob Watts pointed out in the comments, "the state is dependent on more than just the number of coins in the pile" so even though Alice could win if they started at 56, she won't win in this situation. In the first case, she could remove 24 coins at the start, in the second she can only remove 1,2 or 3 coins and Bob will respond by removing either 1,2 or 1 coins, respectively.

Comment: Small remark: in case Alice was previously presented a power of $2$, say $2^a$, and had picked up $A$ coins, now Bob finds smallest power of $2$, say $2^b$,  greater than $A$, and picks up $B=2^b-A$ coins. This next presents Alice with $2^b*(2^{a-b}-1)$ coins, and she is allowed to take not more than $B<2^b$ coins. Alice cannot win since Bob can play $t=2^{a-b}-1$ times the game in a row, Alice each time being presented same power of $2$ (namely $2^b$). Note that if one cannot win with maximum allowed coins to pick up $m$, one cannot win with maximum allowed coins to pick up $c<m$ either.

Comment: Also, @hexomino, I don't think induction needs even (or 2 or 4). Induction is rather by power $a$ of $2$ for Alice starting with $n=2^a$.

Comment: There is a simple variant of the puzzle, where, from second move onward, current player can put coins back onto the pile, but, strictly less than amount previous player took from the pile. And, in case previous player put coins back onto the pile, current player must take coins from the pile (cannot put coins back onto the pile). The answer is the same (as verified by computer program). The strategy and proof are most probably similar.

Comment: FYI: there happens to be an oeis entry A038712 related to this puzzle. It is 1,3,1,7,1,3,1,15,1,3,1,7,1,3,1,31,1,3,1,7,1,3,1,15,1,3,1,7,1,3,1,63... being amount of ways one loses given n coins and maximum m coins 1<=m<=n to take (where 0's are not in the series for odd numbers for which one will always win no matter which m).